# The message window is hidden in the delphi XE7 IDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

The compiler message window is hidden in my Delphi XE7 IDE. I tried selecting Messages in the View menu a number of times and nothing shows. I also tried selecting Messages under the Window menu and still nothing. I can not see the warnings, errors and hints. This makes it very hard to see what the errors, warning and hints are.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Reset the layout from view->desktops menu.

Comment: That worked. Thanks Sertac. Appreciate the help.